# Can not import key value to app service certificate

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

In the first step of certificate configuration, I couldn't set key vault, I have tried to create a new one, but still not work.

There is always to show this error.

```
Failed to link certificate with the selected Key Vault. Check below errors for more detail.:
An error has occurred.
```

Comment: Could you include more details on the steps you did?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site)?

I just bought a new App Service Certificate and created a new vault, I can store it successfully.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have following it and it not work at the first step, I'm not sure there is something wrong on my subscription or not.

Comment: @Aixasz Can you find any more details in the portal?

Comment: @Aixasz You can try again, it this still does't work, you can raise a support ticket on azure portal by following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request  Hope it helps.

Comment: I have token a look in activity log and there is show failed record and message inside is `Internal Server Error`

Comment: @Aixasz If recreate doesn't help, I am afraid that you need to contact Azure support for further assistance.